# I want one ROS app to communicate multiple ROS controllers. Example?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want one ROS  app to communicate multiple ROS controllers. Need example since I am sure someone has already done this.

Basic ros::init (argc,argv,name,options) seems to read the environment flag for ROS_MASTER_URI.

So the other ros::init API must solve the problem, but can I get a complete example of special remappings like __name, __master, __ns, etc.  that would handle multiple ROS masters? After each init I would then cache the node handle.  And, what is this remapping list ?

And could I pass the ROS_MASTER_URI. as a remapping without calling the basic ros::init and relying on the shell environment variables?

TIA.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271580/i-want-one-ros--app-to-communicate-multiple-ros-controllers.-example?/) by [rosnutsbolts](https://answers.ros.org/users/28002/rosnutsbolts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, afaik this is not possible: there is a 1-to-1 mapping between nodes and processes in ROS1 as most important data structures are singletons / global.

Invoking `ros::init(..)` multiple times will not do what you want it to.

In ROS 2 this is different (ie: multiple nodes in a single process is expressly supported), but even there it will most likely require some magic with partitioning and other tricks.

---

Edit: could you maybe clarify what it is that you want to exactly? I'm not sure I understand what "I want one ROS app to communicate multiple ROS controllers" means.

It sounds like you're implying a client-server relationship between the master and any ROS nodes, but that doesn't exist.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0